# Can't seem to get video height for AVPlayerLayer

Tags: ios, video, avplayer

I can't seem to get the height of the video from the URL I have. Every time I log the playerLayer.videoRect.bounds.size.the height returns 0.000. Any help would be appreciated on how to adjust the playerLayer's height based on the video.

I have the playerLayer's height set to half the height of the view just to get the video to show up.

Here is my edited code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videoURL];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

AVAssetTrack* track = [[AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL] tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
CGSize size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform);
CGFloat videoWidth = size.width;
CGFloat videoHeight = size.height;

NSLog(@"%f wide, %f high)", videoWidth, videoHeight);

self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.bottom, self.view.bounds.size.width, videoHeight);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];
[self.player play];
self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AvAssetTrack` to get size of video.

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4";
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];

AVAssetTrack* track = [[AVAsset assetWithURL:url] tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
CGSize size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform);
CGFloat width = size.width;  // 640
CGFloat height = size.height; // 360
```

*Note*: You should put it in background mode because it will block main thread until finish get size success.

Comment: Thank you for the answer on getting height, now it has all this whitespace around the video. I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: I eventually figured it out. I took the original width of video and found what the percent of decrease in size was and just applied it to the height so it would downsize the height proportionately. Thank you for your help Luan.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- You are asking for this information too soon. Like everything else about video, gathering the video's size takes time.
- You have the dependency order backwards. The `videoRect` depends upon the layer's bounds. But you have not given it any bounds; it has zero size.